# Remove a specific list of SKAction from a SKNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction, sknode

During the development of some interactions between different nodes, I realized I need to remove a specific list of actions from a node.
The current version of `Sprite-Kit` framework provides some instance methods as:

- [removeAllActions()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483030-removeallactions)
- [action(forKey key: String)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483138-action)
- [hasActions()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/sknode/1483081-hasactions)

Obviously every action that running in my node has a `String` key for its identifications.
So I thought of something that was very similar to `removeAllAction`, then I made an `SKNode` extension:

```
public extension SKNode {
    func removeAllAction(in list:[String]) {
       list.forEach { if self.action(forKey: $0) != nil { self.action(forKey: $0)?.speed = 0.0; self.removeAction(forKey: $0)}}
    }
}
```

And in my project I can use it as:

```
let actionList = ["idle_walk_sx","idle_walk_dx","walk_dx","walk_sx","walk_idle_sx","walk_idle_dx","rotate_sx_dx","rotate_dx_sx"]
self.removeAllAction(in: actionList)
```

The code works well.
But I'm not really sure about two factors:

- the effectiveness of the `speed` corrections (to zero), I thought it
  appropriate to introduce it in the face of repeated actions. Should I remove it due to avoid strangness or leave it ?
- How is it possible to extend this extension (expanding it) to any
  childrens that have the same list to remove?

Comment: where and when are you setting the speed, on what, and why?

Comment: The `speed = 0` is not needed,  when you remove an action, it is immediate, so during the evaluateActions phase it will not get called.  Also the `if list.count > 0` is not needed as well since the `forEach` will take care of count 0 for you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Good point , I agree.

Comment: can an idle_walk_sx and idle_walk_dx happen at the same time?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Umh, not for my case but generally could happen, what do you think about?

Comment: well I would not bother adding multiple keys to your action,  I would have 1 action ket called animation_state, and use the userData to define the actual state name of the action

Comment: this way you are not needlessly cycling through a ton of animation states just to remove the 1 (or 2) you are looking for

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the node could have other actions out of the current animation state (direction..), for example you can jump and move to the left meanwhile animate your character..

Comment: That is fine,  userData could store the action keys currently attached to the sprite, and when you want to remove the actions,  you just loop through what is in the userData

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Ah right!, good possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments. Probably `speed` is not necessary so the code + the scanning to the children nodes could be something like:

```
public extension SKNode {
    func removeAllAction(in list:[String]) {
        list.forEach { if self.action(forKey: $0) != nil { self.removeAction(forKey: $0)}}
        self.children
            .filter { $0.hasActions() }
            .forEach { $0.removeAllAction(in: list) }
    }
}
```